# Erase duplicate of first 2 char in vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, vector, duplicates, erase

I have a vector of strings containing elements in this format : `$A,1,2,3,4`
I would like to erase duplicate of strings only based on the 2 first characters `$A`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){

    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    vec.push_back("$A,1,2,3,4");
    vec.push_back("$B,1,6,8,1");
    vec.push_back("$A,1,2,5,9");

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());

    for(auto &entry: vec)
        std::cout << entry << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I want to keep only one string starting with `$A`in my vector but this codes is comparing if the whole string is unique.

For example: if the string is `$A...; $B...; $A...; $B...` the output would be `$A...; $B...`

Comment: I think i misread the quesiton. If you had a second string starting with `$B` you also would want to keep only one of those strings?

Comment: Yes, if there is a second string starting with `$B` i want to erase it

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>>` ?

Comment: Why not rather not vec.push_back(some_string) if the first part of some_string is alread in vec.

Comment: @nada I guess you're right, it is better to not push rather than pushing then checking after

Comment: @Juju ... and if you separate the key ($A, $B, ...) from the values and use a `map` or `unordered_map`, the check is built-in so if you try to insert a key that already exists, it'll report back that it didn't insert it.

Comment: I would parse this strings into some struct (this looks like a CSV) and then build some `map` from this data, this filtering based on first two characters is something strange and hard to maintain. Also note if those two strings have matching two first characters but rest is different, which value is more important? First one? or lexical smaller?

Comment: Thanks Ted and Marek I will look at that !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use proper predicate (compatible with the one with sort), something like:

```
vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                      [](const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs){
                          return lhs.substr(0, 2) == rhs.substr(0, 2);
                      }),
          vec.end());
```